# Alternative to WebDAV (what does docs.live.com use?)

Tags: .net, webdav, office-2007, office-2010

Currently I have a simple WebDAV solution.  However when using Microsoft Office it only plays well with IE.  I'd like to know what alternative (and possibly in the same breath, what docs.live.com is doing) way to implement a WebDAV like solution.

This is a .NET shop, so solutions in that stack are highly preferred.

To further expand on the problem:
In IE you have to use a Javascript/ActiveX hack to have the document open up in an editable format.  Obviously the ActiveX won't work on Firefox.  So I'd like a solution that opens a web document up for editing and is browser independent.

CMIS seems to be a good solution, open to any other similar recommendations.

Answer (score 1):

I think [SharePoint](http://sharepoint.microsoft.com/) is the Microsoft alternative.

Comment: Not at all interested in a bloated solution.  Would rather require IE than install SharePoint.

Answer (score 0):

Silverlight 4 supports COM, so you could use that to open your documents in the appropriate Office application.

This article has more than you need, but might help. http://www.silverlightshow.net/items/MS-Word-Mail-Merge-with-Silverlight-4-COM-Automation.aspx

I'm pretty sure docs.live.com (office.live.com) uses Silverlight to view and edit documents in the browser, so that's probably also what they're using to open the documents in the desktop Office applications.